# List of All Installed APP for each user in AD

Tags: powershell, system-administration

I have written a PowerShell script that should generate a report with all installed applications for each AD user.
Unfortunately, it only remembers one list and returns the same list of apps each time. Additionally, the list of applications is not complete. What am I doing wrong?

```
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName


foreach ($user in $users) {
    $username = $user.SamAccountName
    $displayName = $user.DisplayName

 

    $wmiSoftware = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Filter "InstallLocation IS NOT NULL AND Vendor IS NOT NULL AND AssignmentType = 1 AND Not Name LIKE '%Update for%'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

     $wmicSoftware = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {
        $wmicOutput = & wmic product get Name /format:csv | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object { $_.Name -ne $null }
        $wmicOutput.Name
    }

     $registryPaths = @(
        "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*",
        "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
    )

 

    $registrySoftware = Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {
        foreach ($path in $using:registryPaths) {
            Get-ChildItem "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\$path" |
            Get-ItemProperty |
            Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -and -not $_.SystemComponent -and -not $_.ParentKeyName } |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
        }
    }
 

    $installedSoftware = $wmiSoftware + $wmicSoftware + $registrySoftware
    $uniqueSoftware = $installedSoftware | Select-Object -Unique
    $reportContent = @"
<html>
<head>
<style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Zainstalowane aplikacje - $displayName ($username)</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Nazwa aplikacji</th>
</tr>
"@

    foreach ($app in $uniqueSoftware) {
        $reportContent += "<tr><td>$app</td></tr>"
    }

    $reportContent += @"
</table>
</body>
</html>
"@
    $desktopPath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
    $reportFolder = Join-Path -Path $desktopPath -ChildPath 'raporty'
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $reportFolder)) {
        New-Item -Path $reportFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    $reportFileName = "raport_$username$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')).html"
    $reportFilePath = Join-Path -Path $reportFolder -ChildPath $reportFileName
    $reportContent | Out-File -FilePath $reportFilePath
}
```

I have tried to retrieve the list of applications from various locations, but unfortunately, I still don't have all the records. Additionally, I'm not sure what could be the cause of not retrieving the list for each user in AD.

Comment: In your foreach loop you are querying WMI on your local machine for each user. So you only get the result for your local machine. But as far as I know, installed applications aren't saved "per user": applications are installed on a machine (even if they are only installed for a single user it's still per machine).

Comment: is there any chance to fix taht ? or is any soft aviable to check taht apps ??